# How to NIntegrate multiple ranges of data at the same time with an output that can be plotted?

Tags: numerical-integration, procedural-programming, splines

I am trying to use the NIntegrate function to find the difference in the area beneath two 2 dimensional splines (how much area of the river bed was lost or gained from one year to the next) but, I cannot figure out how to do this repeatedly at 1m intervals along the splines in a way that will give me values I can add directly to a plot (without having to copy/paste or hard-code the output). An ideal output would resemble something similar to {{1,x1}, {2,x2},etc.} or be a format that can be converted to something plottable (I'm aware the explanation may be confusing but I am teaching myself Mathematica with no coding and barely any useful computer knowledge beyond Microsoft Office.

Below is the only loop method I have been able to use that gives me the value of the NIntegrate of each interval, but the output for each calculation is its own individual cell and obvious Prints it, rather than being in a useful format (as far as I can tell). "Testing" is Spline1 minus Spline2 and the image below is a screenshot of part of the output of this line of code.

`For[i = 0, i < 21, i++, Print[NIntegrate[Testing, {x, i, i + 1}]]]`

[image]

This screenshot is a plot of the 2 splines being compared.
[image]

Any help or tools I could be directed to that might help solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand what output you are looking for. May be this? `testing = x^2/3; {#, NIntegrate[testing, {x, #, # + 1}]} & /@ Range[0, 20]` This gives `{{0, 0.111111}, {1, 0.777778}, {2, 2.11111},....etc.` which you can now plot using `ListPlot` for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given two splines, with simple examples chosen below:

```
spline1[x_] := 1.21 x^2;
spline2[x_] := (x+1)^2;
```

Plotting these:

```
Plot[{spline1[x], spline2[x]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

> [image: spline1 and spline2]

Then the accumulated difference between them over a range (e.g. x from 0 to 10) can be found using `NDSolve`:

```
sol = NDSolve[{d'[x] == spline2[x] - spline1[x], d[0] == 0}, d, {x, 0, 10}]
```

This saves the continuously accumulated difference starting at $x=0$ as a function `d[x]` in `sol`. This difference can be plotted by:

```
Plot[d[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 10}]
```

> [image: accumulated difference between spline2 and spline1]

`NDSolve` is often useful machinery for collecting numerical integration results over a range of input values. Since we know these functions are continuous, it should also be the case that for any `x1` and `x2`, `NIntegrate[spline2[x] - spline1[x], {x, x1, x2}] == (d[x2] - d[x1] /. First[sol])`.

```
NIntegrate[spline2[x] - spline1[x], {x, Pi, 2 Pi}]
d[2 Pi] - d[Pi] /. First[sol]
```

> 17.5573
>
> 17.5573

`First` is only necessary here because `NDSolve` can potentially find multiple solutions for much more complicated systems, and `d[x] /. sol` would return all of them. In this case, there's only the one so the first one is also the one we are interested in.

Comment: I managed to incorporate parts of the method you used to get my desired result. Thank you for the help. I will try to add my final result below to show exactly what it was I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Below was my adaptation of the answers above to get the result needed (I am the one who initially asked the question)

This is my first time doing any type of coding and teaching myself so some aspects may look slightly primitive and be obvious to some people.

Finding the Difference between the two splines.

```
DamThree1u2119 = SpDamThree1u2021[x] - SpDamThree1u2019[x]
```

NIntegrate to get the difference in area beneath each spline at 1m intervals, showing the positive and negative differences between the data taken in 2019 and 2021

```
DamThree1u2119AreaDif = NIntegrate[DamThree1u2119, {x, #, # + 1}] & /@ Range[0, 30]
```

giving the below values

```
 DamThree1u2119AreaDif = {0.549036,0.734469,0.014559,0.0222887,0.0912996,0.0882717,0.100567,0.133802,0.0854523,0.0744483,0.068068,0.119126,0.135407,0.141813,0.113952,0.095985,0.0809483,0.0797658,0.135477,0.056064,-0.0131309,-0.0272682,-0.0428288,-0.0856341,-0.248317,-0.354404,-0.337383,-0.506746,-0.568715,-0.716076,-0.854683}
```

Code used to get the BarChart shown below

```
BarChart[DamThree1u2119AreaDif,BarSpacing->0,ColorFunction->Function[{y},If[y>0,Green,Red]],ColorFunctionScaling->False,PlotRange->{-1.5,1.5},Axes->{False,True},ImageSize->300,AxesLabel->{None,HoldForm["Area\nchange\n(m^2)"]},LabelStyle->{GrayLevel[0]},Background->LightGray]
```

[image]

Code used to display the splines to see downcutting/filling (red/green respectively) of a cross profile of a river bed, shown below.

```
DifDamThree1u2119=Plot[{SpDamThree1u2021[x],SpDamThree1u2019[x]},{x,0,31},PlotRange->{{0,31},{96,101}},Filling->{1->{2}},FillingStyle->{Red,Green},PlotStyle->{Directive[RGBColor[0.77,0.45,0.98],Thick],Directive[RGBColor[0.7,0.69,0.3],Thick]},Background->LightGray,PlotLabel->"1u 2019-2021",AxesLabel->{HoldForm["(m)"],HoldForm[Elevation[m]]},ImageSize->300]
```

[image]

Looking at river bed change between the years 2018, 2019, and 2021 combined

```
Title1u=Panel[Style["Cross Profile Change 1u",White,20],ImageSize->900,Background->Lighter[Gray, 0.5],Alignment->Center];
Deploy@Grid[{{Title1u,SpanFromLeft},{DifDamThree1u2119,DifDamThree1u1918,DifDamThree1u2118},{DifChartDamThree1u2119,DifChartDamThree1u1918,DifChartDamThree1u2118}},Spacings->{0,0},Dividers->{All,False}]
```

[image]

Thanks to everybody who answered and hope this can be of some use to anybody else.